# How to chain promises in Clojure

Tags: clojure

In Scala, you can use `map` and `flatMap` to run functions on the successful result of a future.

```
val x: Future[Int] = ...
val y: Future[String] = x.map(_.toString)
```

Is there a better Clojure analogue to this than:

```
(def x (promise))
(def y (future (str @x)))
```

Won't the above block a thread while it waits for delivery of `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clojure code won't block until you try to dref the value of y i.e

```
(def x (promise)) ;wont block
(def y (future (str @x)))  ;wont block
(print @y) ;will block
```

As far as analogy is concerned, the code looks fine. But if you want some sort of more declarative way of chaining futures, which is conceptually reduction, then you could use `reduce` as shown below:

```
(def x (promise))
(def final (reduce #(future (%2 @%1)) 
                   x 
                   [inc dec (partial + 10) str]))

(deliver x 10)
@final => "20"
```

You could even come-up with a macro which is similar to threading `->, ->>` macros but create futures for each threaded expression, but I think that would be an overkill when you could do this using normal function.

Comment: While thread that executes `(def y (future (str @x)))` won't block, won't it spawn a thread in the background to execute the `(str @x)` part? And won't that block?

Comment: Is that anything I should be concerned about (i.e., is the pool sharply bounded)?

Comment: @Huw as for as I know you cannot attach callbacks to futures as in Scala. The thread is from an unbounded thread pool. So you should probably be only concerned when you create huge amount of futures.